# Basic java: getting a list of attached nodes

Tags: java

so I have a list of basic nodes, for example nodes A B C.

each component can see what it is attached to for example:

a->b

b->c

c->a

I want a way that I can get a list of all the nodes in the graph. However, I'm running into trouble as my current system can't detect if it has already reached a point. EG in the above example it will go a->b->c->a->b etc. How can I detect this or how can I solve this problem.

My current "solution" `getList()` in the `Node` class:

```
ArrayList<Node> tempList = new ArrayList<Node>();

    tempList.add(this);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < nodesAttachedTo.size();i++){
        tempList.addAll(nodesAttachedTo.get(i).getList());
    }

    return tempList;
```

Comment: Have you looked at either [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)? You need to keep track of previously visited nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `HashSet`. It will not allow one element to be added twice.

Here's an example code that first creates the graph similar to your example, then starts at some point in the graph and goes through it.

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Node
{
    private HashSet<Node> nextNodes = new HashSet<Node>();

    public Node()
    {
    }

    public void addNextNode(Node node)
    {
        nextNodes.add(node);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // this builds the graph of connected nodes
        Node a = new Node();
        Node b = new Node();
        Node c = new Node();

        a.addNextNode(b);
        b.addNextNode(c);
        c.addNextNode(a);

        //this is the set that will lsit all nodes:
        HashSet<Node> allNodes = new HashSet<Node>();

        // this goes through the graph
        a.listAllNodes(allNodes);

        System.out.println(allNodes);
    }

    private void listAllNodes (HashSet<Node> listOfNodes)
    {
        // try to put all next nodes of the node into the list:
        for(Node n : nextNodes)
        {
            if (listOfNodes.add(n))          // the set returns true if it did in fact add it.
                n.listAllNodes(listOfNodes); // recursion
        }

    }
}
```

This goes from one node to all the nodes this node knows. (say that really fast three times)
Until it hits a dead end (= a node it already visited)

I chose to use a `HashSet` in the Node itself to store all the nodes it knows.
This could also be an `ArrayList` or whatever. But as I don't think there should be a connection twice, a `HashSet` seems to be a good choice in this situation, too.

Comment: it will not add the same element twice but it will not terminate either if I just change the data type

Comment: @John what do you mean by data type exactly? Your question mentions no change of a data type. Please elaborate.

Comment: sorry maybe data type is the wrong word. If I change my list to a hashset it will still loop infinitely since there is no way of detecting if an we have been there before

Comment: hey @John, I uploaded an example. Maybe I confused something. In my example, each node knows some other nodes. That creates the graph. Then there's a separate HashSet when going through the graph that keeps track of all the nodes, which is what I thought you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your notation, but you could use two pointers to solve your issue. Start with two pointers that point to the same node. Increment one pointer until it returns to the start. Some pseudocode is below.

```
ArrayList<Node> tempList = new ArrayList<Node>();
Node head = nodesAttachedTo.get(0); //get the head of the list
tempList.add(head);
Node runner = head;
runner = runner.next;
while (!runner.equals(head)) {
    tempList.add(runner);
    runner = runner.next;
}
```

Comment: I'm using my own implementation of Node. Is there anyway I can not use .next?

Comment: Please post your implementation of Node.

Comment: Also, some explanation would help. What is nodesAttachedTo?

Comment: nodesAttachedTo is just a List<Node>

for example if a->b then a's nodesAttachedTo is b and b's nodesAttachedTo is null

Answer (score 0):

A hashmap is probably the way to go here. It allows constant time access (some overhead required, but I'm assuming you want a solution that scales well) to any element in the map.

```
HashMap<String, String> specificSolution = new HashMap<String, String>();
specificSolution.put("a", "b");
specificSolution.put("b", "c");
specificSolution.put("c", "a");
// To get all nodes in the graph
Set<String> nodes = specificSolution.keySet();
```

I implemented with String here because you don't provide a definition for the Node Class in your question, but it can be easily swapped out.

There are many different ways to represent a graph and each has their own limitations/advantages. Maybe another might be more appropriate but we would need more information about the problem.